# Testing paypal initiation in NestJs with Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, paypal, nestjs

I am writing test for a Service method in NestJs where the method initiates Paypal Payment intent. I run the `yarn test:watch` or simply `yarn test` command the test written below runs and passes but after the test is complete it throws the following error.

`TEST`

```js
describe("PaymentsService", () => {
  let paymentsService: PaymentsService
  let paymentRepository
  let ordersService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StripeModule.forRoot({
          apiKey: "stripe.apiKey",
          apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        PaymentsService,
        { provide: PaymentRepository, useFactory: mockPaymentRepository },
        { provide: UsersService, useFactory: mockUsersService },
        { provide: OrdersService, useFactory: mockOrdersService },
        {
          provide: Stripe,
          useFactory: () => ({
            checkout: {
              sessions: {
                create: jest.fn(),
              },
            },
          }),
        },
      ],
    }).compile()

    paymentsService = module.get<PaymentsService>(PaymentsService)
    paymentRepository = module.get<PaymentRepository>(PaymentRepository)
    ordersService = module.get<OrdersService>(OrdersService)
  })

  describe("initiatePaypalPayment", () => {
    it("will initiate paypal payment", async () => {
      ordersService.getOrder.mockResolvedValue(mockOrder)
      ordersService.calculateOrderPrice.mockResolvedValue(mockOrder.price)

      jest.doMock("paypal-rest-sdk", () => {
        return jest.fn(() => ({
          payment: {
            create: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
          },
        }))
      })

      expect(
        await paymentsService.initiatePaypalPayment(
          { orderId: 10, voucherCode: "string" },
          mockedResponse
        )
      ).toEqual(undefined)
    })
  })
})
```

`TEST RESULTS`

```bash
 PASS  src/payments/payments.service.spec.ts
  PaymentsService
    initiatePaypalPayment
      ✓ will initiate paypal payment (117ms)

  console.log src/payments/payments.service.ts:72
    initiatePaypalPayment

  console.log src/payments/payments.service.ts:86
    totalPrice:  1000

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.926s, estimated 6s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.

  ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
    Attempted to log "Error in paypap Error: Response Status : 401
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/app/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:130:23)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
        at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
      response: {
        error: 'invalid_client',
        error_description: 'Client Authentication failed',
        httpStatusCode: 401
      },
      httpStatusCode: 401
    }".

      91 |         payment_method: 'paypal',
      92 |       },
    > 93 |       redirect_urls: {
         |                         ^
      94 |         return_url: 'www.example.com',
      95 |         cancel_url: 'www.example.com',
      96 |       },

      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (../node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:130:23)
      at processTicksAndRejections (../internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
        response: {
          error: 'invalid_client',
          error_description: 'Client Authentication failed',
          httpStatusCode: 401
        },
        httpStatusCode: 401
      }".
      at console.log (../node_modules/@jest/console/build/CustomConsole.js:183:10)
      at payments/payments.service.ts:93:25
      at ../node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/api.js:102:13
      at ../node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/api.js:87:9
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (../node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:140:13)

/home/user/Desktop/app/src/payments/payments.service.ts:94
                throw new common_1.InternalServerErrorException();
                ^

InternalServerErrorException: Internal Server Error
    at /home/user/Desktop/app/src/payments/payments.service.ts:115:15
    at /home/user/Desktop/app/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/api.js:102:13
    at /home/user/Desktop/app/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/api.js:87:9
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/app/node_modules/paypal-rest-sdk/lib/client.js:140:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  response: { statusCode: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error' },
  status: 500
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

is it because I haven't mocked the `paypal-rest-sdk` the correct way or there could be another reason for the error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 invalid_client / 'Client Authentication failed' error from the PayPal API occurs for one of two reasons:

- REST APP/API credentials are incorrect. Obtain a clientid + secret from https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , and ensure your code is configured correctly to use them
- You are using sandbox API credentials in live/production mode, or vice-versa. The two environments are completely separate and credentials from one will never work in the other.

Comment: I don't think we need to use the apikeys when testing the method, do we?

Comment: If your test involves calling the PayPal API to obtain an access token (which apparently it does), then yes you do.

Comment: I understand that you need an api key for testing but where to provide the api key in the test above, am I missing some piece of code in there? that will initialize the paypal sdk and will require the use of api key?

Comment: Using the PayPal REST API, be it with the SDK or not, requires a client id and secret